# How to see files on data/data/your.app.package/ dir on device

Tags: android, ddms

I want to see files on my data/data/your.app.package/ dir on device by Eclipse File Explorer but it can works on device but works on emulator.

[image: My File Explorer on device]

Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to security reasons you will not be able to see the files in app directory in the device. I am not sure but i think you will be able to see if you rooted your device.
I have never tried rooting a device.

Comment: Yes in rooted device that folder will be visible since emulator is a developer device its rooted one and shows the content of that folder